# How do I change android auto-correct text color?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-xml

I'm currently using an EditText field with a grey background. My problem is that when auto-correction happens, you can't see the grey auto-corrected words against the grey background. Is there a way to change the default font used by auto-correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the appearance of pretty much everything by theming your application. That would also be the way to go to customize the appearance of your EditText.

[Read the Styles and Themes guide at Android Developers.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyingStyles)

I recommend you have a look at the themes.xml file of the emulator of your target platform. It's located in android-sdk/platforms/android-X/data/res/values.